# Dangling else in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, dangling-else

I have this doubt guys, I don't know; any example to understand will be great.
Does the Kotlin programming language suffer from the "dangling else" problem?
If the problem is there then what is the reason in that case?

Comment: This explains the "dangling else" problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else.  Now do some experiments :-).   (The Kotlin reference doesn't explicitly state how dangling else is dealt with ... unlike Java for example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin uses the same methodology as java when it comes to eliminating the dangling else problem. The "else" keyword is simply linked automatically to the nearest "if" or "when" keyword. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#if